# Channel Videos - outputting nothing

Tags: channel-videos

EE 2.9.3
CV 3.2.0

I'm having some trouble getting channel videos to ouput code. For troubleshooting purposes I set up a test template with nothing in it except the example code from the [docs](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/videos/) - bottom of the page. The only thing I've done different is hard code an entry_id that I know has channel videos content.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="not foo" entry_id="131"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>

    {exp:channel_videos:videos entry_id="131"}
        <h3>{video:title}</h3>
        {video:embed_code}
    {/exp:channel_videos:videos}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any idea why this would not be working? The title of the entry is displayed correctly but nothing from the channel:videos tag shows up.

Comment: What version are you using? I've heard a bunch of buzz about a recent update that fixed things with v3 of the YouTube api...

Comment: @jchrono-battle updated post with version (3.2.0)

Comment: Switched to Antenna, interface not as nice, but it works.

Comment: Having same issue, looks like there is no solution. Company won't answer posts.